# Is it possible to serialize string to json with single slashes?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have following class

```
class MyClass{
    String str = "D:\folder1\folder2\folder3\file.txt"
    ....
}
```

I serialize object of MyClass to json. In json I see that my `str` looks like `D:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\file.txt`

Is it possible to ask GSON don't add double slash?

Comment: Are you sure your string is `D:(formfeed)older1(formfeed)older2(formfeed)older3(formfeed)ile.txt"?` `\f` is an escape for a form feed control character in both Java and JSON.

Comment: "D:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\file.txt".replace("\\\\","\\") will do the trick.

Comment: @gstackoverflow: If the library did *not* double the slashes, it would be wrong. You know how you need to double the slashes in Java? JSON also works like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [JSON specification](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt) states

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks,
>   except for **the characters that must be escaped**: quotation mark,
>   **reverse solidus**, and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F).

Therefore the `\` must be escaped for the JSON to be valid. There is no way around this.

Note that your parser will also remove the second `\` when reading the JSON, so it should not be an issue.