# json writer adding extra slash to the serialized file

Tags: java, json, jsonresult

In JSONObject I have put `{"text":"\folder1\folder2\filename.txt"}`.

It is serialized as `{"text":"\\folder1\\folder2\\filename.txt"}` instead of `{"text":"\folder1\folder2\filename.txt"}`.

Why is it adding extra forward slash?

Comment: like this {"\\folder1\\folder2\\filename.txt"}

Comment: That's not valid JSON either way, there's no key.

Comment: The extra slashes are probably escape characters (i.e. `\\` represents `\` and `\n` represents newline). Your post on StackObverflow already unescaped the extra backslashes.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts {"text","\\folder1\\folder2\\filename.txt"} it's like this

Comment: That's also invalid JSON.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: sorry {"text" :"\\folder1\\folder2\\filename.txt"} like this

Comment: Please edit your question then.

Comment: but is the object as expected when you deserilize?

Answer (score 0):

Therefore the \ must be escaped for the JSON to be valid.according JSON spec. your parser will also remove the second \ when reading the JSON.

read this [JSON spec](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt).read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429194/is-it-possible-to-serialize-string-to-json-with-single-slashes)